# How to write function that measures frequency of each line (objects) - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a function create_dictionary(filename) that reads the named file and returns a dictionary mapping from object names to occurrence counts (the number of times the particular object was guessed). For example, given a file **mydata.txt** containing the following:

```
abacus
calculator
modern computer
abacus
modern computer
large white thing
modern computer
```

So, when I enter this:

```
dictionary = create_dictionary('mydata.txt')
for key in dictionary:
print(key + ': ' + str(dictionary[key]))
```

The function must return the following dictionary format:

```
{'abacus': 2, 'calculator': 1, 'modern computer': 3, 'large white thing': 1}
```

Among other things, I know how to count the frequency of words. But how does one count the frequency of each line as above?

Here are some constraints:

- You may assume the given file exists, but it may be empty (i.e.
  containing no lines).
- Keys must be inserted into the dictionary in the order in which they
  appear in the input file.
- In some of the tests we display the keys in insertion order; in others were sort the keys alphabetically.
- Leading and trailing whitespace should be stripped from object names
- Empty object names (e.g. blank lines or lines with only whitespace)
  should be ignored.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Like I said, right now, I am chewing my cuticles. I know how to handle words in a text file, but frequency of phrases, I am paralysed.

Comment: Ok, use a dict in python

Comment: please clarify how to apply a dictionary in this case

Comment: @Pamela, so how do you count words in a text file?

Comment: you mean you dont know?

Comment: There should be a `1` behind `calculator` I assume? Order in dictionaries is tricky, it only works for insertion (as of python 3.7) but you cannot order alphabetically (you might need an `OrderedDict` then).

Answer (score 1):

One easier way to achieve is use the following

Let the file name `a.txt`

```
from collections import Counter
s = open('a.txt','r').read().strip()
print(Counter(s.split('\n')))
```

The output will be as follows:

```
Counter({'abacus': 2,
         'calculator': 1,
         'large white thing': 1,
         'modern computer': 3})
```

Comment: If we use the output script I have provided, the answer is still being problematic.

Comment: Closing parenthesis missing in `print()` statement.

Comment: It doesnt work even if the paranthesis is edited...not in the format that is expected

Comment: Also, "Counter" is not present (as shown in the sample expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Further to what @bigbounty has suggested, here what I could come up with.

```
from collections import Counter
def create_dictionary(filename):
    """Blah"""
    keys = Counter()
    s = open(filename,'r').read().strip()
    keys = (Counter(s.split('\n')))
    return keys
```

So, if I type:

```
dictionary = create_dictionary('mydata.txt')
for key in dictionary:
   print(key + ': ' + str(dictionary[key]))
```

I get:

```
abacus: 2
calculator: 1
modern computer: 3
large white thing: 1
```

But I need some help with "How to print nothing if the text file is empty?"

For example: consider an empty text file ('nothing.txt'). The expected output is blank. But I dont know how to omit the default value ' **: 1**' for keys. Any advise?

Comment: If the file is empty, you can use `open('a.txt','r').read() == ''` that results to true

Comment: But the function must identify if the text-file is empty, and if so, the function must print blank. How can I accomplish that? Currently I am getting ": 1" as output. But I need the output to be blank.